# jQuery - triggering show(),hide() on button click

Tags: jquery

With my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/L2Ssq/32/), I made it to highlight on one of main menu buttons when loaded and show() and hide() corresponding button set in the bottom.

What I think is wrong but can't figure out myself is something to do **$this** variable's reference scope in my switch statement. In my case, $this points to the clicked button value which I presume is the name of the class but in my switch statement, I am not sure whether I can reference the id names from **$this**. I guess my question is what value does **$this** hold in my scenario?

It would be nice to see a working example, possibly with less code as I can see many duplicates where it could be simplified.

```
$('.menu').click(function () {
    if ($(this) != $('.highlight')) {
        $(this).addClass('highlight')
            .siblings('.menu')
            .removeClass('highlight');
    }
    switch ($this) {
        case '#dateMenu':
            $('.date-chart').show();
            $('.jc-chart').hide();
            $('.jp-chart').hide();
            $('.ws-chart').hide();
            break;
        case '#jcMenu':
            $('.date-chart').hide();
            $('.jc-chart').show();
            $('.jp-chart').hide();
            $('.ws-chart').hide();
            break;
        case '#jpMenu':
            $('.date-chart').hide();
            $('.jc-chart').hide();
            $('.jp-chart').show();
            $('.ws-chart').hide();
            break;
        case '#wsMenu':
            $('.date-chart').hide();
            $('.jc-chart').hide();
            $('.jp-chart').hide();
            $('.ws-chart').show();
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I would have thought:`switch (this.id) ... case ("wsMenu")` - but you likely just need to hide the siblings and show $this once you set $this=$(this) - and you need $(this).hasClass('.highlight')

Comment: put a `debugger;` in your code and open up your console in firefox or chrome. `console.log(this)`

Comment: where is `$this` ?? i guess that should be `$(this)` which again makes no sense.. :)

Comment: That is not an answer

Comment: rather you should put that in comments.

Comment: Technically we could just change all answers to "Debug  your problem"

Comment: switch ($(this).prop('id')) and then in your case statements, remove the # sign

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. Your suggestion worked well. Can you please elaborate more on ideas of using siblings that could replace my switch blocks?

Comment: See @bipen's answer. I was on my mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this` should be `$(this)` ... this is the refrence to the current element... since you are checking the id. use `prop()` .

```
 switch ($(this).prop('id')) {  or  switch (this.id) { ...
```

and remove the `#` form the case

try this

```
 $('.menu').click(function () {
if (!$(this).hasClass('.highlight'))) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight')
        .siblings('.menu')
        .removeClass('highlight');
}

switch ($(this).prop('id')) {
    case 'dateMenu':
        $('.date-chart').show();
        $('.jc-chart').hide();
        $('.jp-chart').hide();
        $('.ws-chart').hide();
        break;
    case 'jcMenu':
        $('.date-chart').hide();
        $('.jc-chart').show();
        $('.jp-chart').hide();
        $('.ws-chart').hide();
        break;
    case 'jpMenu':
        $('.date-chart').hide();
        $('.jc-chart').hide();
        $('.jp-chart').show();
        $('.ws-chart').hide();
        break;
    case 'wsMenu':
        $('.date-chart').hide();
        $('.jc-chart').hide();
        $('.jp-chart').hide();
        $('.ws-chart').show();
        break;
}
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/L2Ssq/36/)

**updated**

for reduced code... you can use siblings().

```
 switch ($(this).prop('id')) {
    case 'dateMenu':
        $('.date-chart').show().siblings().hide();

        break;
    case 'jcMenu':

        $('.jc-chart').show().siblings().hide();

        break;
    case 'jpMenu':

        $('.jp-chart').show().siblings().hide();

        break;
    case 'wsMenu':

        $('.ws-chart').show().siblings().hide();
        break;
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/L2Ssq/38/)

Comment: +1 but please fix the erronous `if ($(this) != $('.highlight'))` which I believe should be `if (!$(this.hasClass('.highlight'))`

Answer (score 1):

`($this)` is wrong without assigning, instead use `this.id`

You can use indeed like

```
var id = this.id;
switch (id)
```

> **And remove `#` in your cases and make like below**

```
switch (this.id) {
        case 'dateMenu': //removed #
            $('.date-chart').show();
            $('.jc-chart').hide();
            $('.jp-chart').hide();
            $('.ws-chart').hide();
            break;
        case 'jcMenu':  //removed #
            $('.date-chart').hide();
            $('.jc-chart').show();
            $('.jp-chart').hide();
            $('.ws-chart').hide();
            break;
        case 'jpMenu':  //removed #
            $('.date-chart').hide();
            $('.jc-chart').hide();
            $('.jp-chart').show();
            $('.ws-chart').hide();
            break; 
        case 'wsMenu':  //removed #
            $('.date-chart').hide();
            $('.jc-chart').hide();
            $('.jp-chart').hide();
            $('.ws-chart').show();
            break;
    }
```

Working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Ssq/34/)

Comment: $this=this.id is poor documentation. $x normally signifies that the var is a jQuery object.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for pointing the mistake.  From googling, http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-code-smells/ I came to know it is an ugly practice.  But anyother reason?

Comment: IF you use $this, THEN make sure it is $(this). IF you use $mydivs THEN make sure it is $("some selector returning divs") - if your code is to be self documenting do NOT use a var that has a name that confuses a reader. If you do not want to use $ then that is fine. It would still be `id = this.id` or in this case no need to save it at all since we only use it once.

Comment: You are welcome. PS: With 2.5K rep, you should update your profile with name/avatar :)